Unable to provide build number while publishing results in azure Test Runs using WebApi
We are trying to publish our test results to azure test runs automatically using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi
We want to publish Test Name , Result, Status, Build Number.
We are able to publish all fields except build number.
Our tests will be executed on multiple build numbers and we need to add build numbers for tests.
We tried all parameters in TestcaseResult, RunupdateModel, TestRun but unable to provide build number. Can you please help in this aspect
We are using code as provided in
Add Test Result to a test run(testcase) in VSTS
Expecting solution for publish build number

Can you update the question and share your current code sample? From the link you shared, it contains several code snippets

I have shared a C# sample in my answer about linking the build to the test run. Based on my test, the UpdateTestResultsAsync doesn't support linking the build to test result. We need to link the build to the test run at the  CreateTestRunAsync action. You can have a try.


Unable to provide build number while publishing results in azure Test Runs using WebApi

Based on my test, I can reproduce the same issue when using the sample to update the test result.
When we pass the build number to the UpdateTestResultsAsync method, it will not link the build to the test result.
Even if I use the corresponding Rest API: Results - Update, I also not able to link the build to test result. The C# method and Rest API may not support this feature.
To solve this issue, you can pass the build id to the CreateTestRunAsync method.
Here is the C# Sample:
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;



namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var u = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/Orgname");
                VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "PAT"));
                var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
                var testClient = connection.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();
                int testpointid = 215;
                string teamProject = "ProjectName";
                int InPutbuildid = 26700;
                RunCreateModel run = new RunCreateModel(name: "test123", plan: new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.ShallowReference("1403"), pointIds: new int[] { testpointid }, buildId: InPutbuildid);
                TestRun testrun = testClient.CreateTestRunAsync(run, teamProject).Result;
         
                
                TestCaseResult caseResult = new TestCaseResult() { State = "Completed", Outcome = "passed", Id = 100000 };
                var testResults = testClient.UpdateTestResultsAsync(new TestCaseResult[] { caseResult }, teamProject, testrun.Id).Result;
                RunUpdateModel runmodel = new RunUpdateModel(state: "Completed");
                TestRun testRunResult = testClient.UpdateTestRunAsync(runmodel, teamProject, testrun.Id, runmodel).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

Result:

